# PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress. 4

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, apache

My site keeps giving the error "Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress."

I have rhel6 + php5.3.3 + php-mysql + wordpress + apache installed on one server. On a seperate server we have mysql + mysql-server installed.

In wp-config.php I configured our mysql server.
I have been seeking for solutions for over a day now but I cannot seem to fix it.
I tried adding/ uncommenting the extension=mysql.so & mysqli.so line in php.ini but that didn't do anything either. 
The phpinfo.php page gives info back, only thing is that scan dir for additional ini's is not looking at the right dir. Don't know if that can cause this problem though.

Anyone an idea?

With kind regards,
Bram

Comment: can you post output of "php -m" command?

Comment: PHP WarningL Module 'mysql' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP WarningL Module 'mysql' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
apc
bz2
calender
Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
ereg
exif
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gd
gettext
gmp
hash
iconv
json
ldap
libxml
mbstring
mcrypt
mysql
mysqli
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
pdo_sqlite
Phar
readline
Reflection
session
shmop
SimpleXML
sockets
SPL
sqlite3
standard
tokenizer
wddx
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
xsl
zip
zlib

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that an installation of PHP via yum install has a default config and disables a lot, like this config option --without-mysql.
I downloaded PHP from their site and compiled it myself with my own config and this worked.
I also found that this problem does not occure on CentOS7, a yum install of php, php components and mariadb works fine with wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required.
Only one thing causes that error. Your PHP.INI doesn't have the mysql line uncommented, so it's not loading the mysql module (or the module is simply missing entirely).

Restart your webserver after you fix the PHP.INI file.

Comment: I tried that, I uncommented the lines extension=mysql.so and extension=mysqli.so and restarted apache but no luck there.

Comment: ps. I also tried adding the full path to it as well.